# Google Tag Manager Trigger for Data Layer is not Showing the Tag

Tags: google-analytics, tags, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have been reading the new documentation for Google Tag Manager, and based on that have created a custom event which looks like this:
[image]

[image]

Here event is the key and the value is Shop Now Start. I am pushing this in the Data layer in my website. But at the point, where these key value pairs are pushed in my data layer, the respective tag is not being triggered.

Besides the event key/value pair, how can I go about setting a trigger that is fired when a key value pair has a certain value (e.g. userId='12')

Also, when I am setting the trigger, can I set the value to be boolean false? (e.g. isNew='true'

Comment: Don't include the curly brackets. Event name is just "Shop Now Start", not the complete key/value pair.

Comment: what about the other items in the data layer. for e.g. let's say if I wanted to set the trigger if userId='12', then do I need to include the key?

Comment: No. events you can simply use by  their names (they are a bit of a special case), else you have so create a new variable in the tag manager interface, give it a name, set it's type to "dataLayer" and enter the key whose associated value you want to get from the dataLayer. Then you can use the name of your GTM variable to address the value in your tags.

Comment: okay im sorry for asking basic questions. I am just beginning to learn this. So let's say i create a dataLayer variable called userId. The key that I am pushing to my dataLayer is also called userId. This means that my GTM variable will get the right value that is pushed in my website code, right? So now how do I set a trigger that checks if userId='12' then launch the corresponding tag? also can this value be a boolean , e.g. false

Comment: @EikePierstorff: please let me know what is the best way of doing this, I really am stuck!

Comment: If you want to fire an event based on the userId, then you can do that by filling out the section that says "Fire this trigger when all of these conditions are true." for your custom event trigger. Make sure you have created a dataLayer variable that matches the key you want to use, ie. "userId". Your condition can be "userId equals 12" or "userId equals false". Lastly, remember that you have to include an event to fire the tag on as well.

Comment: @nyuen thanks very much for your informative reply. I am still facing issues because GTM is not firing the tag, could you take a look at this question and verify if I am doing this right

Comment: As @Eike pointed out, set the event to fire on 'Shop Now Start' only. See if that works for you. Remember to test in Preview mode first and when you make the datalayer push, check what shows up in the debug window under "data layer".

Comment: @nyuen thanks for your tips. I realized the problem was that my website is a single page architecture, so instead of creating a custom event, I had to create a history event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my website is a single page architecture. So custom Event triggers don't work. So instead need to create a history change trigger